# A word or phrase for when someone who is highly respected and thought well of, doesn't meet those expectations

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I'm looking for a word or phrase that describes the effect of when someone is over-hyped, and when they don't meet expectations, they're criticised much harsher than they would have been if they weren't over-hyped. I hope this makes sense

Comment: A ***fall from grace***? A ***[milkshake duck](https://twitter.com/pixelatedboat/status/741904787361300481?lang=en)***?

Comment: [The bigger they are, the harder they fall](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/bigger-they-are-the-harder-they-fall)

Comment: A related term, used when someone has been represented as being more dangerous or powerful than they are later found out to actually be is "paper tiger."

Comment: That seems like a huge range of possibilities. Could you narrow it down a lot with at least two example sentences?

Answer (score 1):

> **Feet of clay** is an expression now commonly used to refer to a weakness or character flaw, especially in people of prominence.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feet_of_clay)

> feet of clay (cf. Dan. ii. 33 ‘his feet part of iron and part of clay’): a fundamental weakness in someone supposedly of great merit.

[OED-3](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/34027?redirectedFrom=feet+of+clay#eid9320789) - (Subscription required)

Comment: I think Nigel's *feet of clay* is about as close as will be possible…

Answer (score 0):

An underachiever or disappointment.